# Como conseguir a tabela com os dados que geram o gráfico com o comando DECOMPOSE no R

Tags: r

Boa tarde, pessoal. Eu gerei esse gráfico com o comando "decompose" no R. O que eu gostaria de saber é como extrair os dados de cada uma dessas componentes para uma tabela. Por exemplo, eu quero gerar o gráfico do "random" no Excel e preciso dos dados dessa série.
[image: decomposição da série temporal da UR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo o `help` da função `decompose`

```
require(graphics)

m <- decompose(co2)
plot(m)
```

se você utilizar `names(m)` verá que são salvos 6 "objetos" dentro de `m`: `x`, `seasonal`, `trend`, `random`, `figure` e `type`. Agora é só você selecionar os dados do seu interesse com o operador `$`. No caso da sua dúvida,

```
m$random
```